# SQL Alter Sequence on remote server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sequence, linked-server

On SQL Server, I'm trying to alter sequence on a remote server using this:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE SeverName.DbName.sys.SeqName_sequence RESTART WITH 1000;
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Does anyone know if this is possible and the correct syntax?

Comment: And the error is ...? If you look at the documentation, you will see that you can only alter a sequence in the current database - only a two-part name (schema.sequence) is allowed.  Connect directly to the instance and database and run your alter script there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using dynamic SQL, and specify that database's `sp_executesql` procedure.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
ALTER SEQUENCE SomeSchemaName.SomeSequenceName RESTART WITH 1000;
';

EXEC SeverName.DbName.sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```